# Como fazer uma janela ficar acima de todas?

Tags: python, tkinter

Não sei se é possível fazer isso, por isso nem vou colocar nem um Código aqui. Minha duvida é a seguinte, se é possível fazer uma janela ficar na frente de todas as outras janelas, e não estou falando de (TopLevel), queria que a janela do programa ficasse na frente de todas as outras, incluindo janela do windows, Exemplo: estou com a janela do Chrome aberta, ai ao abrir o programa ele fica em cima da janela do Chrome, porem deixa com que eu mexa no Chrome.

Existe alguma solução possível? O TopLevel funciona para janelas do python, queria que funcionasse para todo o sistema.

Comment: Por que os votos para fechar? A pergunta está bem articulada, e a resposta certa vai ser "não", ou o nome da função pra chama - independe do trabalho que ele já fez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tem uma resposta legal no S.O. me inglês aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front

Basicamente é chamar o método `.attributes` da sua janela, mandando setar o `"-topmost"` para `True`:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> w = tkinter.Tk()
>>> w.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente pelos meus testes! fico extremamente grato por sua contribuição! :3